# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B on live but not local server

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, knockout.js, amazon-ec2

So i am making some ajax post and it seems to work fine on the localhost, but when I publish it to ec2 server on amazon, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B. Which seems to point to JSON parsing failure. Exact same database, same browser, and same methods being called. Why would it work on local and not on the server.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action")',
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",
                success: function (result) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var errorData = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                    var errorMessages = [];

                    for (var key in errorData)
                    {
                        errorMessages.push(errorData[key]);
                    }
                    toastr.error(errorMessages.join("<br />"), 'Uh oh');
                }
            });
```

Here is the basic layout on the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Action(ViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {

                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                return Json("Successfull");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, string.Format("{0} \n {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                errors.Add(ex.Message);
                return Json(errors);
            }

        }
```

Within the **try** statement, I do a couple of queries to the database and post some calculations on **Authorize.Net (https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx)**

If there are any error with Authorize.net web service calls then I return errors like this:

```
if (profile.resultCode == MessageTypeEnum.Error)
{
     logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, string.Join(",", profile.messages.Select(x => x.text)));
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
     List<string> errors = new List<string>();
     profile.messages.ToList().ForEach(x => errors.Add(x.text));
     db.SaveChanges();
     return Json(errors);
}
```

This error that I am logging:

```
    A public action method 'AddPromoCode' was not found on controller 'Flazingo.Controllers.PositionController'. at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
```

completedSynchronously)

Comment: This sounds like a server problem.  Can you share the server-side code behind @Url.Action("Action")?

Comment: @CodeThug I added the server side codes.

Comment: @CodeThug any ideas. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

You have another post at [can't find action only on live server, works fine in local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199361/cant-find-action-only-on-live-server-works-fine-in-local-server), so I'm guessing that this post is specifically related to the javascript pieces, not the server-side pieces.

It sounds like something bad happens on the server, the server sends back some type of error, and the your error handler (in javascript) dies when trying to handle that response.

> I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B. Which seems to point
>   to JSON parsing failure.

That sounds quite reasonable.  Let's look at the code:

```
.ajax({
  ...
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var errorData = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
      var errorMessages = [];
      ...
  },
  ...
});
```

I would highly recommend taking a look at what `xhr.responseText` is.  My guess it that it does not contain valid JSON, so the parseJSON method throws the 'Unexpected token B' error.

To look at this value, you could put `console.log(xhr.responseText);` or you could use a tool like the javascript debugger in your web browser or fiddler to see what is there.

My guess is that the server is sending back a string with something like `There was an error on the server` instead of JSON like you are expecting.  I see that you have error handling built in - my guess is that there is an error within your error handling, and there is nothing to catch it.  I would recommend doing debugging on the server side to see if there is an error somewhere that you are not expecting.

Perhaps profile.messages is something that can only be enumerated once, and when you try to do it again it throws an error.  Or maybe DB.SaveChanges is throwing an error for some reason.  Either of these would result in the logged message that you see with the behavior you see on the client side.

Comment: The exception is occuring at the $.parseJSON. I created a test action that only return a error. No server side computation.

Comment: So what is the value of xhr.responseText?  Seeing that should add light to the situation.

Comment: Please note that although your test action does not do any server-side computation, there is likely computation being done by server-side frameworks such as MVC, and `xhr.responseText` likely contains an error being thrown by a framework for some reason that the javascript isn't expecting.  Seeing the error (by examining `xhr.responseText`) will help us see where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to return a 400 response (Bad Request) with your own custom response content.

I think that IIS by default doesn't allow you to do this, and as CodeThug mentioned, may be replacing your custom JSON content with a server message.

But it appears that you can override this behaviour:

http://develoq.net/2011/returning-a-body-content-with-400-http-status-code/

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have received similar mysterious errors in the past when using ASP.NET script bundling on knockout and bootstrap, especially when including the already-minified versions in a bundle.

If you are running in DEBUG mode on localhost, then ASP.NET will not be minifying the javascript libraries. However, once you deploy, you are presumably no longer in DEBUG mode and now minifying/bundling the scripts. Sometimes the bundling/minification of these scripts can result in syntax errors similar to the one you posted.

If so, you may be able to load knockout from a CDN to avoid the need for bundling.

Comment: Ah i see. This might be the issue. I have return just a JSON(Error = true) and it still occurs. So I am leading to think this might be it. I will test it out.

Comment: Although one thing to note, I don't have any bundling since I am MVC3. I did use the Web Essential tools to minify some of the of the js.

Answer (score 0):

It seems JSON sending as the response from the server is badly generated

```
ex: if a value in the database is hi "my" friends

    JSON file will be generated as text:"hi "my" friends"
```

so value for property text is badly generated.

double check values in production/development server for such values.

best practice is replace quotes with escape character

```
ex: text:"hi \"my\" friends"
```