# can't find action only on live server, works fine in local server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, knockout.js

> A public action method 'AddPromoCode' was not found on controller
>   'Flazingo.Controllers.PositionController'. at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Position/AddPromoCode',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset:utf-8",
            data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
            success: function(result){
                if(result.TypeId == 1){
                    viewModel.promoOff(viewModel.grandTotal() * (result.Value / 100));
                    viewModel.PromoCodes.push(promoCode + ": "+ result.Value + "% off");
                }else{
                    viewModel.PromoCodes.push(promoCode + ": "+ result.Value + "days free");
                }
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var errorData = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                var errorMessages = [];
                //this ugly loop is because List<> is serialized to an object instead of an array
                for (var key in errorData)
                {
                    errorMessages.push(errorData[key]);
                }
                toastr.error(errorMessages.join("<br />"), 'Uh oh');
            }
        });
```

EDIT: POST METHOD

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPromoCode(PaymentViewModel model)
        {
            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            try
            {

                var position = db.Positions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PositionId == model.PositionId);
                if (position != null)
                {
                    var promo = db.Promotions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code.ToLower() == model.PromoCode.ToLower() && x.IsUserEntered);
                    if (promo != null)
                    {
                        var promoUsage = db.PromoCodeUsages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PromotionId == promo.PromotionId && x.ClientId == position.Client.Id);
                        int used = 0;
                        if (promoUsage != null)
                        {
                            used = promoUsage.Used;
                        }

                        if (used < promo.QuantityUsage)
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Today >= promo.StartDate && DateTime.Today <= promo.EndDate)
                            {
                                position.PromoCodes.Add(new PositionPromoCode
                                {
                                    PromotionId = promo.PromotionId
                                });

                                var clientPC = position.Client.PromoCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PromotionId == promo.PromotionId);
                                if (clientPC != null)
                                {
                                    clientPC.Used = used + 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    clientPC = new PromoCodeUsage()
                                    {
                                        PromotionId = promo.PromotionId,
                                        Used = used + 1
                                    };
                                    position.Client.PromoCodes.Add(clientPC);
                                }

                                db.SaveChanges();

                                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                                return Json(new { Value = promo.Value, TypeId = promo.PromotionTypeId });

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                                errors.Add("Sorry seems like this promotion code has expired");
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                return Json(errors);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            errors.Add("Sorry seems like you have already used this code, or its not applicable anymore!");
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return Json(errors);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        errors.Add(string.Format("Sorry we don't have '{0}' promocode in our system!", model.PromoCode));
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(errors);
                    }
                }

                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                errors.Add("We coudn't find this position in our system!");
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(errors);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, string.Format("{0} \n {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                errors.Add("Sorry there was internal errors, flazingo.com has been notified.");
                return Json(errors);
            }
        }
```

JSON Structure:

```
{"PositionTitle":"Testing B Syntax Error","PromoCode":"FREECB","FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"Address":null,"SuiteNumber":null,"PhoneNumber":null,"City":null,"State":null,"ZipCode":null,"CreditCardNumber":null,"ExperationMonth":null,"ExperationYear":null,"CCV":null,"ClientId":2,"CustomerProfileId":64277420,"PositionId":78,"EmailAddress":"jmogera@gmail.com","Years":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"2013","Value":"2013"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2014","Value":"2014"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2015","Value":"2015"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2016","Value":"2016"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2017","Value":"2017"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2018","Value":"2018"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2019","Value":"2019"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2020","Value":"2020"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2021","Value":"2021"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2022","Value":"2022"}],"MonthList":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"Jan","Value":"01"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Feb","Value":"02"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Mar","Value":"03"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Apr","Value":"04"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"May","Value":"05"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Jun","Value":"06"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Jul","Value":"07"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Aug","Value":"08"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Sep","Value":"09"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Oct","Value":"10"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Nov","Value":"11"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Dec","Value":"12"}],"IsAddingNewCard":false,"HaveCardOnFile":true,"AddOns":[{"PositionId":78,"ProductId":2,"Description":"The heart and soul, we take you through the hiring process, start to finish and give you every tool you need to make a great hire along the way.","Price":39,"HasAdded":true,"AutoRenew":true,"Name":"Complete Hiring System","AddOnId":122}],"CreditCards":[{"CreditCardId":16,"LastFour":"1060","HolderName":"Barrett Kuethen","ExpDate":"/Date(1422766800000)/","IsDefault":true}],"CardOnFile":{"CreditCardId":16,"LastFour":"1060","HolderName":"Barrett Kuethen","ExpDate":"/Date(1422766800000)/","IsDefault":true},"PromoCodes":[],"__ko_mapping__":{"CardOnFile":{},"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"PositionTitle":true,"PromoCode":true,"FirstName":true,"LastName":true,"Address":true,"SuiteNumber":true,"PhoneNumber":true,"City":true,"State":true,"ZipCode":true,"CreditCardNumber":true,"ExperationMonth":true,"ExperationYear":true,"CCV":true,"ClientId":true,"CustomerProfileId":true,"PositionId":true,"EmailAddress":true,"Years[0].Selected":true,"Years[0].Text":true,"Years[0].Value":true,"Years[1].Selected":true,"Years[1].Text":true,"Years[1].Value":true,"Years[2].Selected":true,"Years[2].Text":true,"Years[2].Value":true,"Years[3].Selected":true,"Years[3].Text":true,"Years[3].Value":true,"Years[4].Selected":true,"Years[4].Text":true,"Years[4].Value":true,"Years[5].Selected":true,"Years[5].Text":true,"Years[5].Value":true,"Years[6].Selected":true,"Years[6].Text":true,"Years[6].Value":true,"Years[7].Selected":true,"Years[7].Text":true,"Years[7].Value":true,"Years[8].Selected":true,"Years[8].Text":true,"Years[8].Value":true,"Years[9].Selected":true,"Years[9].Text":true,"Years[9].Value":true,"Years":true,"MonthList[0].Selected":true,"MonthList[0].Text":true,"MonthList[0].Value":true,"MonthList[1].Selected":true,"MonthList[1].Text":true,"MonthList[1].Value":true,"MonthList[2].Selected":true,"MonthList[2].Text":true,"MonthList[2].Value":true,"MonthList[3].Selected":true,"MonthList[3].Text":true,"MonthList[3].Value":true,"MonthList[4].Selected":true,"MonthList[4].Text":true,"MonthList[4].Value":true,"MonthList[5].Selected":true,"MonthList[5].Text":true,"MonthList[5].Value":true,"MonthList[6].Selected":true,"MonthList[6].Text":true,"MonthList[6].Value":true,"MonthList[7].Selected":true,"MonthList[7].Text":true,"MonthList[7].Value":true,"MonthList[8].Selected":true,"MonthList[8].Text":true,"MonthList[8].Value":true,"MonthList[9].Selected":true,"MonthList[9].Text":true,"MonthList[9].Value":true,"MonthList[10].Selected":true,"MonthList[10].Text":true,"MonthList[10].Value":true,"MonthList[11].Selected":true,"MonthList[11].Text":true,"MonthList[11].Value":true,"MonthList":true,"IsAddingNewCard":true,"HaveCardOnFile":true,"AddOns[0].PositionId":true,"AddOns[0].ProductId":true,"AddOns[0].Description":true,"AddOns[0].Price":true,"AddOns[0].HasAdded":true,"AddOns[0].AutoRenew":true,"AddOns[0].Name":true,"AddOns[0].AddOnId":true,"AddOns":true,"CreditCards[0].CreditCardId":true,"CreditCards[0].LastFour":true,"CreditCards[0].HolderName":true,"CreditCards[0].ExpDate":true,"CreditCards[0].IsDefault":true,"CreditCards":true,"CardOnFile":true,"PromoCodes":true},"copiedProperties":{}},"addNewCreditCardValidationGroup":{"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"Address":null,"City":null,"State":null,"CreditCardNumber":null,"ExperationMonth":null,"ExperationYear":null,"CCV":null,"errors":[]},"promoOff":0,"grandTotal":39}
```

Note: the call is made within a knockout click function.
Note: I have created another issue, thinking it was client side issue. This is related.
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B on live but not local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069730/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-b-on-live-but-not-local-server?noredirect=1#comment22944514_16069730)

Comment: Can you post your action method?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Added the action method!

Comment: Hey jmogera could you post json structure too, which is being expected from that method.

Comment: @Jai Added the JSON Structure

Comment: @Jai error also occurs on non-JSON posts.

Comment: What does PaymentViewModel look like on the server side?  Does the JSON structure match it?

Comment: Yes the paymentviewmodel matches the JSON

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the client, actual JSON, or code *in* the action method. The error is "Action not found on controller": have you triple-checked (some rubber duck debugging may help) that all the paths, configs, and factories are working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find `AddPromoCode` so, there seems a url problem. You should add the application name at ajax code in server like `url: '/ApplicationName/Position/AddPromoCode'`.

You can also do this with url.action html helper, like:

```
// In layout or view:
@Html.Hidden("urlPrefix", Url.Action("", ""))

// In Javascript
var baseUrl = $("input#urlPrefix").val();

$.ajax({ url: baseUrl + '/Position/AddPromoCode', ...
```

The part `Url.Action("", "")` creates `'/ApplicationName'` part dynamically.