# Ajax can't find action on server but work on local

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#form").submit(function (e) {
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Admin/SecureLogin/',
                data: { tdn: $('#tdn').val(), pw: $('#pw').val(), gn: $('#gn').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data == "Login failed"){
                        $('#error').text("Tên đăng nhập hoặc mật khẩu không đúng");
                    }
                    if(data == "OK"){
                        window.location.replace("/Admin/Home");
                    }
                }
            });
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // this is better than "return false"
        });
    });
```

and controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
    public string SecureLogin(string tdn, string pw, string gn)
    {
        Car4RentContext db =  new Car4RentContext();
        var query = (from l in db.Account where l.UN == tdn && l.PW == pw select l).SingleOrDefault();
        if (query != null)
        {
            if (gn == "")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(query.UniqueId.ToString(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tdn, true);
            }
            //return RedirectToAction("Home","Admin");
            return "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Login failed";
            //return View();
        }
    }
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I test on my local machine, this ajax work well. But when i deploy my website on host, I login and it always return:

POST http://example.com/Admin/SecureLogin/ 404 (Not Found)

I have read this question: [can't find action only on live server, works fine in local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199361/cant-find-action-only-on-live-server-works-fine-in-local-server) but it doesnt work with me.

Here is my view:

```
        <form id="form" class="form-vertical login-form" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: block;">
            <h3 class="form-title">Thông tin đăng nhập</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                    <input id="tdn" class="form-control" type="text" name="tdn" placeholder="Tên đăng nhập">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></div>
                    <input id="pw" class="form-control" type="password" name="mk" placeholder="Mật khẩu">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="error" class="input-group" style="color:red">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <input id="gn" type="checkbox" name="ghinho"> <span>Ghi nhớ</span>
                </div>
                <button class="submit btn btn-primary pull-right">
                    Sign In <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Any ideas for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it :)

The problem is: when I create new action or edit something and upload the file to server, I forgot to build it. In local,I run (Crtl + f5), project is built automatically so it work at local not on server.

Solution: Whenever i change something, I upload changed files and the build in bin dicrectory. Everything work like a charm :)